Control gets out of the Function after a "await http.get(url)" Call
Request your help in understanding the issue. The Function \_loadPrices is called from another function login() by passing salesMan data to get the prices from SAP System.
The login() Function is called from the login Screen.
Login Screen
Below Piece of Code inside Login() Function
_loadPrices(salesmanData);
final loadedPriceList = ref.read(priceListNotifier);

if (loadedPriceList.isEmpty) {
  _showErrorDialog('Failed to load Prices');
  return;
}

Below \_loadPrices() function
Future<void> _loadPrices(salesMan) async {
  // List<PriceList>
  final url = Uri.parse(
      'http://1XX.XX.XX.XXX:9000/sap/ZSD_VS_DEMO_SRV/CSP_PricingSet?\$format=json&\$filter=KUNNR eq \'${salesMan.userId}\'');
  final List<PriceList> loadedPriceList = [];
  final response = await http.get(url);    // Issue Line *******
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      
    // Some code to convert responseData to list loadedPriceList

    ref.read(priceListNotifier.notifier).addPrices(loadedPriceList);

}

The control jumps out of the \_loadPrices function to login() function after the await http.get(url) line.
When I try to login for the second time, it works fine, but with double the data.
I am simply trying to login to a SAP System, load the prices list and display.

await _loadPrices(salesmanData);

Thank you @pskink...  That Solved my issue in no time.. But The _loadPrices(salesmanData); was working fine till yesterday without await.
I just dont remember what change i made in between to cause the issue.

if it worked, it's only a good luck, normally it should not work
